# insertBST in prolog - why it returns false

Tags: prolog

Despite the fact that I traced my program, I can't understand why it returns `false`:

```
insertBST(t(Root, L, R), Root, t(Root, L, R)).
insertBST(nil, Elem, t(Elem, nil, nil)).
insertBST(t(Root, L, R), Elem, t(Root, L, newR)) :-
    Root < Elem,
    insertBST(R, Elem, newR).
insertBST(t(Root, L, R), Elem, node(Root, newL, R)) :-
    Root > Elem,
    insertBST(L, Elem, newL).

?- insertBST(t(11, nil, nil), 15, X).
false.
```

Can you explain it me, please ?

Comment: A couple issues that stand out: (1) `newR` and `newL` are not a variables, but they're atoms, and (2) your 4th clause introduces functor `node` in the 3rd argument, but the others use functor `t` for the 3rd argument.

Comment: thanks. I think that I should take a  relax.